# Do we want this locked question on what old technologies you use even though they're out of date and why?

Tags: discussion, scope, closed-questions, vote-to-delete

There is this question (a community wiki), and it is locked:

> This question exists because it has historical significance .../...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750606/what-technologies-are-you-using-even-though-they-are-embarassingly-out-of-date

Which is basically:

> What old technology that should have been replaced long ago do you still use regularly, and why?

It is [untagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/untagged) and closed as Not constructive. It was originally
asked Apr 15 2009  and closed and locked on Oct 5 2011.

There are 140 answers (I have not gone through them all), and the top voted answers don't encourage me to want to go further. Some answers are mundane at best, and there is at least one mediocre joke.

For example,

> Minesweeper.

and

> Notepad...

and

> My wife...

Is this question and its answers worthwhile keeping on the site, or should we get it unlocked and deleted?

---

*Of interest [other untagged locked posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/untagged)*

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I'd say that its "historical significance" lock put in place almost *six* years ago has lost its significance.

Most of the non-Wikipedia links in the answers are broken.
Only two or three out of the dozen or so images in those answers that are still accessible.
Technologies that no longer work are still listed while answers that are actually relevant to this day and age can't be added.

IMO, the question adds no value to the site and should be removed.

Comment: Also people are going to be harder and harder pressed to even know what some of these technologies are in the fast changing world of programming. It's a bit like a dinosaur - with none of the interest of a dinosaur.. *wish I could make a witty joke right now*

Comment: Not to mention the low amount of total views (the majority most likely amassed 8 years ago), some rather borderline humour etc... This is pretty much my thoughts. I've deleted the post as I can't see any justification for it hanging around - although - if the community really, really wants it to be around I'm not fussed if it remains undeleted. Just wary of unlocking it and we get a delete/undelete etc...

Comment: @JonClements thanks and yes we don't need to go through the whole *delete/undelete, reopen/reclose, meta drama popcorn routine*

Comment: Thanks, @JonClements. We might want to have a similar review of those other [tag:untagged] questions. They've all been locked 5-6 years ago.

Comment: @Cerbrus I could see some use for "questions to ask an interviewer". Textbook off-topic for SO today, and a few joke answers - but a few answers that we may want to preserve.

Comment: the [wedding cake code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686216/what-code-would-you-have-on-your-wedding-cake) is funny

Comment: @JonClements thanks for the deletion. Would you mind slapping a status-completed on this one?

Comment: Now, since the original post in question has been deleted, this meta question serves no purpose. So, should it be deleted as well?

Comment: @sid-m It should remain as a public record.